getting solana-validator: command not found error
I have setup and installed the solana from https://solana.com/docs/intro/installation
and when I do solana-test-validator, its runs fine but when I do solana-validator
it says command not found,
tried changing config set and sudo ~/.bashrc
but no help yet.

I have fixed it by installing the solana again and exporting its path.
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)"
export PATH="/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"

